# how to recover itunes playlist

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, itunes

I have transferred iTunes folder to new PC. When I restored the files to the new iTunes application, the playlists were gone. I would like to recover all of the iTunes Playlists that I had on my old PC. I am looking to do this in just a few easy steps.

Comment: See if this Apple support article helps you.   https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/itunes/itns2998/windows

Comment: Did you Consolidate the library first [or, was it always consolidated]? Did you 'choose library' on first run? [I think on Windows you have to hold Shift to force it to present the 'choose' dialog.]

Comment: @Ramhound - OP isn't trying to synchronise, merely move. So long as the entire folder is consolidated, moved to the same relative position in the new machine [so paths don't change], then correctly selected in iTunes, it will work. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/itunes/itns3230/windows